# Android SDK build tools

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

If i have two or more version of android sdk build tools as shown below then when which one will be chosen by the eclipse while building. IS it anything to with the SDK platform chosen for developing apk.[image]

Here which one will be used either 17 or 19?

Comment: choose latest Android SDK Build-tools

Comment: If i want to use older version is there any way to do it?

Comment: which one eclipse will use 17 or 19 by default?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911762/what-is-android-sdk-build-tools-and-which-version-should-be-used

Comment: i think it's useful for u.

Comment: I have checked that question in that still this question is not answered completely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [build tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html) specifies the toolchain used to build Android projects. In Eclipse you can change which version is used with the project.properties file by specifying `sdk.buildtools`, e.g.

```
sdk.buildtools=17.0.0
```

You will probably never need to do that, as it will use the most recent installed version by default. It is not tightly coupled to the SDK version, and has only been recently split apart from the SDK itself (since version 17).

Comment: What is the difference between Build tools and SDK platform the?

Comment: In sdk why dont they provide Build tools with every version like system image, sdk platform then?

Comment: can u tell me the location of that project.properties file. In package explorer one project.properties file is there but in that there is no such line. Instead its target=android-15 . This i think denotes the SDK platform version not sdk build tools version?

Comment: You are correct about the SDK line. The build tools line isn't necessary, but the project.properties file is just a file under the root directory of the project. It is used exclusively by Eclipse.

Comment: So it means android will by default choose highest available version for BUILD TOOLS. we cant change it. Thats Correct?

Comment: By default, it uses the highest. You can specify which version is used on a per-project basis in Eclipse with the project.properties file (or with the build.gradle file in AndroidStudio). I'm sure there's a way using Maven, also. If you want to change the default, I do not know of a way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47505/discussion-between-nikhil-kumar-and-dave)

Comment: error: Unable to resolve sdk.buildtools property value 'XXX'

Answer (score 6):

If there are different versions for Android SDK Build Tools , By default eclipse uses the most recent version of the Android Build Tools.

But if your project requirement belongs to different version(may be older) , you can do this using following steps.

1. In the root folder of your application project, find the project.properties file.
2. Open the file and specify the Build Tools version by adding a build-tools property on a separate line:

e.g.  **sdk.buildtools =17.0.0**

Comment: error: 
Unable to resolve sdk.buildtools property value 'XXX'