# com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, eclipse

how to fix com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

pic of error [when i click on Run as android application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYjE6.png)

Comment: Answered in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489398/unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0

Comment: on mac OS 10.11 plzz

Answer (score 26):

If you have Android SDK Build-Tools 24 installed, then either uninstall Android SDK Build-Tools 24, or add the following entry to your project.properties file:

sdk.buildtools=23.0.3

Change the buildtools version value to the last pre-24 version of the Android SDK-Tools that you have installed.

It would appear Android SDK Build-Tools 24 require Java version 8

Comment: If he posted the question 1 month ago be sure that he has not Android SDK Build-Tools 24, because it was released today

Answer (score 1):

Please find my solution for above question in eclipse IDE.
Have updated my JDK 1.7-->1.8 by downloading JDK explicitly.

Try this and update me your problem resolved or not.

regards
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Integrating previous post, into Eclipse - Android SDK Manager, I've to click on "Android SDK Build-Tools" versione 24 installed, and click on Delete Package.

[image]