# how to configure my android emulator after upgrade sdk in appcelerator studio?

Tags: java, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I am using java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

After upgrade with latest titanium sdk as 5.3.0.GA and android sdk, I am unable to rub emulator and it gives me error log as below mentioned

```
[INFO] :   Running dexer: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Xmx512M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/android-sdk/platform-tools" "-jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0/lib/dx.jar" "--dex" "--output=/Users/Ashishgajjar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/eswsdvr1/build/android/bin/classes.dex" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/eswsdvr1/build/android/bin/classes" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar" "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.paint/2.0/paint.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/kroll-common.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/titanium.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-accelerometer.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-map.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-calendar.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar" "/Users/Ashishgajjar/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.0.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar"
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
[ERROR] :   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR] :   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
[ERROR] :   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
[ERROR] :   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
[ERROR] :   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
[ERROR] :   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
[ERROR] :   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[ERROR] :   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] :   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[ERROR] :   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[ERROR] :   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[ERROR] :   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[ERROR] :   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Please provide your guidance to fix out above issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means, you are trying use JDK 1.8(Version 52.0) android compiled libraries with 1.7 run-time

Here, `com/android/dx/command/Main` compiled with JDK 1.8, but your current environment pointing to `jdk1.7.0_80.jdk`

Check this - [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990995/com-android-dx-command-main-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

Comment: Hi Konadal, thanks for communicate
I have upgraded latest DJK version 1.8_91 and now its working 
Thanks!!