# How do I get rid of these errors in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am a novice android app programmer and just started to code a game.  I recently found a video where a red square should show up and would be allowed to be dragged.  I made sure of it and copied the code exactly.  Here are all of the pieces of code:

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.onemorelaugh.mads;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //makes full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //gets rid of title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }
}
```

**GamePanel:**

```
package com.onemorelaugh.mads;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/**
 * Created by OneMoreLaugh on 8/7/2016.
 */
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    private MainThread thread;
    private RectPlayer player;
    private Point playerPoint;

    public GamePanel(Context context){
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
        player = new RectPlayer(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100), Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        playerPoint = new Point(150,150);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);

        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (true) {
            try {
                thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            retry = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void update() {
        player.update(playerPoint);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        player.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

**GameObject:**

```
package com.onemorelaugh.mads;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

/**
 * Created by OneMoreLaugh on 8/7/2016.
 */
public interface GameObject {
    public void draw(Canvas canvas);
    public void update();
}
```

**RectPlayer:**

```
package com.onemorelaugh.mads;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
/**
 * Created by OneMoreLaugh on 8/7/2016.
 */
public class RectPlayer implements GameObject {

    private Rect rectangle;
    private int color;

    public RectPlayer(Rect rectangle, int color){
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);


    }

    @Override
    public void update(){

    }

    public void update(Point point){
        rectangle.set(point.x - rectangle.width()/2, point.y - rectangle.height()/2, point.x + rectangle.width()/2, point.y + rectangle.height()/2);
    }
}
```

**MainThread:**

```
package com.onemorelaugh.mads;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

/**
 * Created by OneMoreLaugh on 8/7/2016.
 */

public class MainThread extends Thread{
    public static final int MAX_FPS = 30;
    private double averageFPS;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private boolean running;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public void setRunning(boolean running){
        this.running = running;
    }

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GamePanel gamePanel){
        super();
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.gamePanel = gamePanel;

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        long startTime;
        long timeMillis = 1000/MAX_FPS;
        long waitTime;
        int frameCount = 0;
        long totalTime = 0;
        long targetTime = 1000/MAX_FPS;

        while(running){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            finally {
                if(canvas != null){
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
            timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000;
            waitTime =  targetTime - timeMillis;
            try {
                if (waitTime > 0)
                    this.sleep(waitTime);
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if (frameCount == MAX_FPS){
                averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
                frameCount = 0;
                totalTime = 0;
                System.out.println(averageFPS);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I double checked this code and it worked for the guys in the video.  When I try and run it, (I'm using android studio) the emulator pops up and shows the home screen of a phone after being black for a little.  It is like the app crashed.  Below are the error codes **I get:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
* What went wrong:
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Error:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
Error:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Error:  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Error:Exception in thread "main" 
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.702 secs
Information:59 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Appears to be due to build failing due to low heap size. See messages from _To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap._

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the first `Error` line:

```
Error:java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

And searching exactly this string on Google, the first answer is this post: [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990995/com-android-dx-command-main-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

**Programming tip #1**: When you get an error, the first thing you have to do is to look for the error and ask Google about it.

Comment: Except that question was never answered with an accepted post

Comment: hey so thank you so much!  It ran haha.But now the object isn;t showing up.  Have any ideas for that one while you are at it?

Comment: @cricket_007 That does not mean that there is not an answer for this problem inside. Was simply trying to teach how to troubleshoot errors easily.

Comment: @MattBOneMoreLaugh To be honest, I have no idea. We need info to troubleshoot problems. Keep an eye to you log. Edit the code to push data to the log on the part of the code that do not work well, or simply apply breakpoints and debug it, iterating through the code. Your question do not have an easy answer. Also, being a programmer also means doing a lot of research before asking the community. If you don't do any research and just ask for each problem, two things happen: You do not gain enough experience and also you will never end your projects because they will last forever to be ended xD