# Xamarin Visual Studio Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, sdk, android-ndk

I began to encounter that kind of mistake a few days, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaCew.png)

I found that link

[Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990995/com-android-dx-command-main-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0)

I remove in SDK Manager Build-tool 25.0.1 and i started to delete order, I deleted 23.0.3 as much; i build every deleting step. When i build that steps i take that error;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqVc4.png)

My jdk version : jdk1.8.0_111

My ndk : android-ndk-r13b

My SDK has Android 5.1.1 (API 22) + Android 4.4W.2 (API 20) + Android 4.4.2 (API 19) + All Extras

Comment: Please attach a diagnostic build output log to your post. Please also include your `.csproj`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting JDK 1.7~ ? , could be worth uninstalling your current version and installing 1.7~ to be on the safe side.

Comment: Of course; even firstly i install JDK 1.7; after that error i install JDK 1.8 and now i am using  JDK 1.8

Comment: Did you try JDK 1.7 With just build tools 23.0~ at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

I follow under steps and when i use on ProjectName.Droid, i dont any error.

File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Cross-Platform -> Blank App(Native Shared)

<-- When i use under source and i take errors that titles. -->

File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Android -> Blank App