# Eclipse Not opening after upgrading

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse is not working in windows 7 sp1 but previously it works on win7. After I upgrade to service pack 1 it does not open, it don't show any error message. I don't need to downgrade my windows. Kindly help me.

Any comments and thoughts are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Download latest version of eclipse for windows and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be fine if you try running it with system compatibility. Just try right clicking it and click troubleshoot compatibility. It should work with one of the previous versions.

Comment: Of course i did this compatibility setting but not opening... :(

Answer (score 0):

After update Eclipse to new Version. 
You have to also update relevant `Android SDK Build-tools`

Comment: It won't open then how can i upgrade?

Comment: i found it on  `Android SDK manager`  `build tool`  have revised version but i expect it will work. i am currently updating.. @Chirag Savsani

Comment: This link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911762/what-is-android-sdk-build-tools-and-which-version-should-be-used

Answer (score 0):

**The above problem was Solved**

uninstall the *JDK 8.0* totally. use *JDK version 7* ,
Now it working... Thank u friends.