# how to identify the correct android SDK build?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I just downloaded some of files in the below URL each of them have more than 250MB zip file. I had surprise that Whatever the file I downloaded It doesn't have proper folders.

[http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html][1]

But none of them let me create AVD as higher than API level 18.  And It doesn't have "build-tools", "platform-tools" folders after extracted.

My environment is Windows 7 64 bit, and intel core i5. Also, I just go through there would be some intel CPU image which can improve the emulator performance. So, Can somebody guide to download a proper build which contains "tools", "platform-tools","build-tools" and SDK manager exe file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21193817/3513479

Comment: this is depend on you on which version you want to work

Comment: Is it possible to get the zip file version which contains tools, build-tools,  platform-tools, SDK manager.exe file? nor .exe

Comment: its directly provided bysupportd link you may to download from sdk managaer. from Android studio or eclipse