# What is Android SDK build-tools, platform-tools and tools?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-build, android-sdk-2.3

I know that this is a pretty basic question. But I am new to native android development and I am having trouble wrapping my head around what is what.

I am using the Android Standalone SDK and not using Android Studio so please guide be accordingly.

Let's say that I want to build my app for API level 19. what level of platform tools and build tools do I need to install.

This is what I have currently

[image]

[image]

As I want to build for API 19, which I have installed. Do I need to have version 19 of `Android SDK build tools` or they can be higher?

Kindly please explain to me what each term means as well in laymen's terms.

-Thanks

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911762/what-are-the-android-sdk-build-tools-platform-tools-and-tools-and-which-versio)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Build-Tools is a component
>   of the Android SDK required for building Android apps. It's installed
>   in the /build-tools/ directory

So, build tool is to build your android app. That is like the makefile for C projects. Output is an APK file.

> Android SDK Tools is a component for the Android SDK. It includes the
>   complete set of development and debugging tools for Android. It is
>   included with Android Studio.

So, Platform tool is where all the tool to interact with the android device you have, such as `fastboot` and `adb`. For example, to install your apk into the devices, run it, debug it, and grep some file from it, you need to first connect your device to `adb` bridge and run all those command on it.

> Let's say that I want to build my app for API level 19. what level of
>   platform tools and build tools do I need to install.

Basically, you should have all the latest thing here. If you are deploying for a API 19 device, you should also have the Android SDK platform 19.

I haven't touch those things in a while, because I install all those things anyway, so I'd appreciate correction.

Answer (score 6):

**Android SDK Build-Tools** is a component of the Android SDK required for building Android apps. It's installed in the /build-tools/ directory. It includes the complete set of development and debugging tools for the Android SDK like emulator, sdcard, sqlite and apk builder etc.

For more details check [Android SDK Build-Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)

**Platform-tools** are used to support the features for the current android platform including adb which is acting like a bridge to communicate with emulator or device.

You can also know more about this topic by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193817/4629101)

Comment: Okay so If I want to build for API 19, do I need to have Android SDK Build-Tools version 19 or can I build using version 25

Comment: @krv if you want to build for API 19 then you can use any version greater than or equal to 19.