# Why should we always use the latest build tools in Android?

Tags: android

I was just looking a few open source projects and most of them were using the latest build tools like sdk 25 while right now i am using target sdk 23. I was wondering why should we use the latest target sdk in android i have read the following post but the answer doesn't seems to be satisfactory. 
[What are the Android SDK build-tools, platform-tools and tools? And which version should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911762/what-are-the-android-sdk-build-tools-platform-tools-and-tools-and-which-versio)

Comment: Bug fixes and new features. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html

Comment: build tools gives you additional features and improvements to developing your applications

Comment: As for the question about target sdk, this is a good summary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Comment: same reason why you update anything else.

Comment: what about if the older project we have still using the older build tools....? Won't it be differ for using the latest Build Tools to implements....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By updating the sdk, they are fixing the issue.Like in sdk 25 they are fixed a crash on async socket reconnect and  crash on Mac when glDeleteTextures() is called after the corresponding context was destroyed.

you can see more through this link.
visit: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html

Comment: should i delete the older Build Tools once i used the latest one? Coz it will takes lots of free spaces. And what about the older project reference, will they still works?